# Lotus Workflow - What does the subroutine LWFExecuteNotesAction do?

Tags: workflow, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm working on a Lotus Notes Application that is integrated with Lotus Workflow. As I'm modifying some actions, I always see the subroutine "LWFExecuteNotesAction" being called at the end of the script of the action. I tried to google this and read some books but I couldn't still find it's purpose.

Answer (score -1):

It's an internal call, so wouldn't be documented.

**[edit]** I understand this does not answer your question as you want it.

However it is IBM internal code and the details of what it does are not publicly documented.

You won't even find the source within the Application database, only references to where the precompiled LSS files existed (Q: drive).